# Translating UIViews when orientation changes - SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

I am building a simple Breakout game (game with a paddle, ball, and bricks and you have to break all the bricks) for Stanford's 193p course.  Right now, I have a UIView (that serves as the paddle) added as a subview to an another UIView that serves as the game's view. I did not add any UIViews in storyboard except the game view - everything else is in code.

This paddle uiview is added to a dynamic animator.
It is added when the orientation of the iPhone is vertical.

But, when I rotate the phone, the Paddle UIView repositions to another location and cannot be seen.

What is the best way to and how do I translate this view so that it is in the exact same position in respect to where to was in the vertical orientation to the horizontal orientation?

I do not want it to be removed from the dynamic animator so I do not want to remove the paddle, then find the new location and then add it back.

Comment: you may want to look into using SpriteKit for a simple game like Breakout.

Comment: but the assignment and course pushes you to use this assignment to learn dynamic animation as its main focus. all of the code done in the lectures is done with UIKit.

Comment: Did you hard-code the distance from the top of the screen? Any constraints being applied to keep it a set vertical distance from the bottom? As explained in iOS8 and 9 WWDC videos, an "orientation change" is really just an animated bounds change, so use the app's  bounds (for iOS9 seems better to start thinking in terms of "window" than "screen") to calculate paddle position relatively instead of absolutely. You can also add invisible boundaries to your dynamic animator, though I'd have to look up the specifics.

Comment: The y position of the paddle view is: gameViews.frame.maxY - half the height of the paddle. and the x varies along that axis via a pan gesture